# Open any program from cmd in python

Tags: python, cmd, path, subprocess, command-prompt

I want to open a program located at a specific path in Python but I am getting this error:

[image: Error]

Error in cmd: `The system cannot find the file steam.exe`

```py
import os
os.system('start steam.exe "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam"')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `subprocess`:

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.call(['D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\\steam.exe'])
```